# How to change existing database schema according to new changes in new schema in sql server using c#?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with asp.net MVC.

Scenario is, I am having the License generation application. Where as a each while creating the new license has it creates a separate database according to centralized database script. Say `DBCentralized` is the current central database and after creating 3 licenses `DBLicence1`, `DBLicence2`, `DBLicence3` are three databases. This architecture may not good but client's architects want to follow this. But say I am having any schema wise changes in `DBCentralized` database. Say adding new table, stored procedure, or altering table then certainly this will reflects onward license creations. But what about the existing databases. I need to update existing database schema according to new alterations. since this scenario in short is Updating existing licenses.

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: The question is, suppose I am providing License updates to all existing customer, but they are having their data in their databases. how I can programatically alter existing licenses? how to find what is not exist in current database and alter accordingly ?

Comment: What license? SQL server license? or your own license?. Try to be more specific, maybe adding some schema/data could help.

Comment: As explained in question itself, I am having License generation application. certainly I am developing it. not sql